# Upload image to png

Tags: django, python-imaging-library

How to change extension of uploaded file to "png" in django?

**in views:**

```
def pictures_2png(file):
    return Image.open(file).save('img.png')

Pictures.objects.create_pictures(car, pictures_2png(request.FILES["picture"]))
```

Without `pictures_2png` file saves on hard disk with it old extension (jpg, gif, etc). Something wrong in that function, but if I use it (function) in `ipython` with my local images - it works. Whats wrong? How to fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

via [link](http://morlandi.wordpress.com/2012/07/03/how-to-convert-a-pil-image-to-a-django-file/)

```
def pictures_2png(file):
    buffer = StringIO()
    Image.open(file).save(buffer, "PNG")
    return InMemoryUploadedFile(buffer, None, 'test.png', 'image/png', buffer.len, None)
```